# Not able to get key in nested data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a realtime database in Firebase and have some data looking like this inside a key called "firms":

[image]

I got the user key and wants to find the key where the user is placed. I have tried something like this:

```
let userkey = 'the key that I have for the user'

ref.child('firms').child('users').orderByChild('user').equalTo('userkey').on("value", 
function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Is there something that i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do as follows:

```
  ref
    .child('firms')
    .orderByChild('users/user')   
    .equalTo(userkey)  // Warning: in your question you do equalTo('userkey') with quotes
    .on('value', function (snapshot) {
      console.log(Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]);
    });
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?authuser=0#sort_data), you need to specify the relative path to the nested child in your `orderByChild()` call.